# Linking multiple custom variables in Omniture

Tags: tags, adobe-analytics

I have an implementation in Sitecatalyst, where i have to track categories and the multiple tags associated with the categories. How should i go for it. What should be the variables which should be defined for it in omniture.
for example -

|---------------------|
|       MOOD          | // Main Category 
|---------------------|
| Uplifting           | // Sub Category 
|---------------------|
|  Fun                | // Sub Category 
|---------------------|
| Proud               | // Sub Category 
|---------------------|
|  Fun                | // Sub Category

Answer (score 1):

There are three options:

**Listprop**

You could create a listprop which you can enable in the report suite settings by implementing a delimiter for the traffic variable. This is especially handy if you have the possibility to create multiple levels. You can then implement the traffic variable like so:

```
s.prop1 = "MOOD|Uplifting|Fun|Proud|Fun";
```

Adobe Analytics will automatically split the values based on the pipe character. Please note that listprops don't allow correlations and pathing.

**Multiple traffic variables/props**

The other option would be to create multiple traffic variables and define all of them on every page where they're required.

```
s.prop1 = "MOOD";
s.prop2 = "Uplifting";
s.prop3 = "Fun";
s.prop4 = "Proud";
s.prop5 = "Fun";
```

However, this option will consume a lot of traffic variables of which you only have 75.

**Classification**

The third option would look the same as the listprop, however, you don't configure the traffic variable as a listprop, you configure it as a normal traffic variable and classify it later on using the Classification Rule Builder.

Using the classification rule builder you can split the incoming data by the pipe character (using regular expression) and create new dimensions resembling the categories.

```
s.prop1 = "MOOD|Uplifting|Fun|Proud|Fun";
```

I would personally go for the third option as it doesn't require a lot of props and it allows for a future proof approach of measuring the categories even when you're adding more levels.

Good luck with your implementation!